# Linux module process TCP/IP before firewall

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Is there any way to wrote custom kernel module to process TCP/IP packet before processed on linux firewall ?

this is path i need :

```
     +------------------+      +-------------------------------------+      +-------------+
---> | my custom module | ---> | Linux firewall (Filter, Nat, Mangle | ---> | route table | --> ...
     +------------------+      +-------------------------------------+      +-------------+
```

Comment: You mean like [`tcpdump` see packets that are being dropped by `iptables`?](https://serverfault.com/a/233311/448950) and [`tcpdump` bypass iptables?](https://superuser.com/a/925332/754490) ... So you may take advantage from [`libpcap`](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap) source and or [How to write a `libpcap` module (draft)](https://www.tcpdump.org/libpcap-module-HOWTO.html).

Comment: can use libpcap kernel space ?